# Wp Dropdown Category Not Show Current As Title

Tags: categories, dropdown

Im using wp_dropdown_categories for a page. Issue im having is i dont want it to show the current category that the page is on as the title, i want it always to display the "Select A Category" text i have placed in the options. Current code is:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Select A Category&show_count=1');
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_query_var( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to fetch the current category:

```
$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
```

You can use this `$cat` in the exclude parameter of `wp_dropdown_categories( )` to hide the current category:

```
$args = array(
  'show_option_none' => __( 'Select A Category' ),
  'show_count' => 1,
  'exclude' => $cat
);

wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `exclude` parameter.

```
wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select A Category&show_count=1&exclude=45');
```

Where 45 is your current category ID.

Comment: This will not work for the situation. Please read the question.